# Exporting Salesforce library files as zip using TALEND

Tags: salesforce, talend

I have been assigned with a task to Export the files from the Salesforce libraries in their original format. I have no clue whatsoever to what component to use to achieve this. I do know that it is possible with DataLoader but I would appreciate if anybody can tell me how to do it using Talend.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can go through my notes you will understand How to use Talend MDM tool and your answer is also there .

[Talend MDM Notes link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/tjij043on5fzgr9/Talend%20MDM.docx?dl=0)